# Is there an alternative to gdb for Linux systems?

Tags: linux, gdb, debugging

Please consider both commercial and free debuggers. Would like to see also the pros and cons for each.

Comment: I'd love to get a free debugger on linux that has the visual studio feel. That's the only thing I feel missing.

Comment: I'd love to see an alternative to gdb that didn't crash constantly every time you tried to debug at disassembly level.

Comment: This is one of the most burning questions a Linux developer can have. It is infuriating that the simple question to ask for a list of debuggers besides gdb under Linux, is supposedly "opinion based"  Fortunately a lot of useful answers have been given before this was closed. Also formally the closing is unjustified. A list of debuggers is not "opinion based". It is very debatable if adding a remark to characterise the debugger makes it so.

Comment: A reversible debugger, drop-in replacement for gdb: https://rr-project.org/ (New!!!)

Answer (score 8):

I really like [EDB (Evan's Debugger)](http://freshmeat.sourceforge.net/projects/edebugger/).

It has a nice 'OllyDBG feel', which was great because I used it quite a deal when I was still working on the windows platform.

> EDB (Evan's Debugger) is a QT4 based
> binary mode debugger with the goal of
> having usability on par with OllyDbg.
> It uses a plugin architecture, so
> adding new features can be done with
> ease. The current release is for
> Linux, but future releases will target
> more platforms.

[image]
<sub>(source: [softpedia.com](http://www.softpedia.com/screenshots/thumbs/EDB-Evan-s-Debugger-19734-thumb.png))</sub>

(clickable)

Comment: @Longpoke: nope, link works fine. You may have more luck with the author's own website: http://www.codef00.com/projects.php#debugger

Comment: http://freshmeat.net/screenshots/20/88/2088b56ccd701771c6df012f05708043_medium.png?1267210446

Comment: Last update was Apr. 2011? Is this one still supported/working?

Comment: @NoBugs: See http://code.google.com/p/edb-debugger/source/list - looks like the freshmeat page isn't updated.

Comment: Website updated to https://github.com/eteran/edb-debugger/releases

Answer (score 6):

nemiver is a great front end to gdb (looks better than ddd imo even though it might not be as advanced yet).

Answer (score 6):

On Linux, most debugging is handled via GDB.  As others have mentioned, however, it is not necessary to use GDB directly.  A variety of options exist, some mentioned in previous answers:

- Emacs (has a GDB frontend)
- DDD (Motif-based, somewhat quirky, graphical interface with excellent data inspection capabilities)
- Nemiver (GTK-based frontend)
- Eclipse
- Code::Blocks
- NetBeans can probably do it as well
- Anjuta (Gnome IDE)

Of these, I've used DDD and tried Nemiver.  At the time, Nemiver was short on features, and thus didn't work very well for me.  That was two years ago, though.  I've often used DDD, and find its data viewing excellent and worth working with its UI.  I also frequently just use gdb from the command line, though.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used it myself, so I can't comment on the pros/cons , but one commercial alternative is [TotalView](http://www.roguewave.com/products/totalview.aspx).

There is also [DDD](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/) that gives you a frontend to GDB, but i guess you have already tried/used that?

Answer (score 3):

emacs has a great front end to gdb too.

Comment: Is the next version of emacs going to come with the kitchen sink also?

Comment: ro come on ! Emacs do has a great front end for gdb like any other IDE, what's wrong with this ?! Your comment would be more appropriate to the fact that emacs also comes with tetris...

Answer (score 3):

Sun's `dbx` from Sun Studio works in Linux too.

Answer (score 2):

[zerobugs](http://www.zerobugs.org/)

Comment: Any comments on this one? Have you used it?

Comment: I tried it very briefly but never got it working because of having a to out of date GUI desktop.

Comment: That domain appears to be expired. However, if this is the same sw it's archived here instead: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=zerobugs

Comment: The original link is dead, and so is @jbatista 's archival link... editing.

Answer (score 2):

For debugging Assembly code, there's [ALD](http://ald.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

`UndoDB` sounds interesting, in that it allows "reverse stepping",  however; it's expensive, and I'm well adapted to `gdb`, so I'm unlikely to change. Others I've seen don't have the extra features required to entice me away from the environment that I know.

Comment: UndoDB is more of an 'add-on' to GDB rather than a different debugger.  It is however a good tool.

Answer (score 1):

Going off on a ledge here, but if you're up to it, Sun's MDB is great, especially if you use lots of templates and threaded code. It beats GDB hands down if that's your situation. On the other hand, it's not that great if all you need are breakpoints, I'd stick with GDB in that case.

Answer (score 1):

A good frontend to GDB that hasn't been mentioned is [Insight](http://sourceware.org/insight/).

Comment: A frontend to gdb is not an alternative to gdb IMO.